# Constants in OpalRB

Tags: javascript, ruby, opalrb

I'm wondering about something in a project of mine with OpalRB (the Ruby-to-JavaScript compiler): when you make a constant in Opal, like so:

```
ONE = 1
```

... is that essentially the same thing as saying this is JavaScript?:

```
const ONE = 1;
```

The reason that I ask this question is that the `const` keyword in JS in not always properly supported in each browser and, due to that, I'm somewhat wary about using constants with Opal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ... is that essentially the same thing as saying this is JavaScript?

No it's not. `const` in JavaScript makes a variable that ignores any re-assignments and keeps its original value. In Ruby, constants complain with a warning when re-assigned, but actually do get re-assigned.

Here is how  `ONE=1` in Ruby gets compiled by Opal:

```
$opal.cdecl($scope, 'ONE', 1);
```

As you can see, constants aren't stored as variables the way local variables are, they're stored internally inside the scope object.

The `cdecl` function can do whatever it wants if `ONE` is already declared. The developers of Opal however, seemed to choose to not show a warning when constants are reassigned. Try [this](http://opalrb.org/try/#code:ONE%3D1%0AONE%3D4%0Aputs%20ONE) (it's always fun to play around with this webpage and see how the compiler works).

Therefore, constants in Opal-compiled Ruby aren't.

Comment: Thanks, this made a lot of sense.

Comment: Or, to put it more succinctly: you cannot compile a Ruby constant to an ECMAScript constant because they have completely different semantics.

Comment: Interestingly, however, Ruby strings are compiled to ECMAScript strings, even though they are completely different (Ruby strings are mutable, ECMAScript strings are immutable).

Comment: I feel like Opal isn't meant to be a platform to run already-existing Ruby apps in the browser, but to allow people to code for the browser in Ruby. Maybe this is why strings are not tampered with when converting code.